# PHP If statement with two timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a PHP if statement that says if there are more than 3600 seconds between two MySQL timestamps than do something. I think I have the IF statement written correctly but something is going on where it is always being resolved to true.

```
 $time1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT time_to_sec(max(time)) as time FROM table");
 $time2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT time_to_sec(max(time)) as time FROM table and time <>(SELECT max(time) FROM table)");


 if (($time1->fetch_object()->time) - ($time2->fetch_object()->time) > 3600);
 {
 echo $test
 }
```

When I run:

```
 echo $time1->fetch_object()->time-$time2->fetch_object()->time;
```

It shows the correct value that I would expect but even if its less than 3600 it still does the echo $test. Any ideas what can be causing this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: You have a superfluous semicolon behind the `if()`, ending the statement right there

Comment: WOW! Thank you! I completely missed that. Much appreciated for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Use **CASE** statements,  a better and efficient approach:

```
Select event, case when  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_timstamp, first_timestamp)<3600 then   `under_time` when TIMESTAMPDIFF(last_timstamp, first_timestamp)>3600 then `over_time` end case   as `duration_flag` from your_table where your_conditions
```

Then in your **PHP** you condition the output based on the queried flag.

This way you make less requests to the server,  and has a cleaner query.

Maybe **mysql** has an old bug with  TIMESTAMPDIFF,  so if it doesn`t work,  use this instead:

```
Time_To_Sec(last_timstamp) - Time_To_Sec(first_timestamp)
```